# I want to assign a number for each alphabet(for eg, A=1,B=2,C=3,etc.,) in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

So I am creating an app which inputs the text and when I hit the "Submit" button, it should convert each alphabet to it's respective numbers and perform sum of digits to get a final single digit answer. Can someone guide me on how to go about this? I am a beginner to Dart programming language and I can't seem to relate the logic

```
 import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:luckynumberapp/Calculate.dart';
    import 'package:luckynumberapp/about.dart';
    
    void main() {
      runApp(MyApp());
    }
    
    class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
    }
    
    class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
      var name, value;
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          theme: ThemeData.dark(),
          home: Builder(
            builder: (context) => Scaffold(
              backgroundColor: Colors.black,
              appBar: AppBar(
                iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
                backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                title: Text(
                  'LUCKY NUMBER',
                  style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Pacifico', letterSpacing: 4),
                ),
              ),
              body: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 10, 20, 30),
                child: Center(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      TextField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          hintText: 'Enter a word/name',
                          labelText: 'Enter',
                        ),
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                        onChanged: (name) {
                          value = name;
                          value1 = name;
                        },
                      ),
                      RaisedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => screen2(value: value),
                          ));
                        },
                        child: Text('Submit'),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              drawer: Drawer(
                child: ListView(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.red),
                      accountName: Text('Yogesh Prakash'),
                      accountEmail: Text('test@dev.com'),
                      currentAccountPicture: CircleAvatar(
                        child: Image(
                          image: AssetImage(
                              'Image/105769079_10217500208479055_1053899048265455769_n.jpg'),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    ListTile(
                        title: Text('About'),
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AboutPage()),
                          );
                        })
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this it works perfectly, the sum is printed in the console after you click on the submit button, hope this helps

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  String value;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark(),
      home: Builder(
        builder: (context) => Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          appBar: AppBar(
            iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
            title: Text(
              'LUCKY NUMBER',
              style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Pacifico', letterSpacing: 4),
            ),
          ),
          body: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 10, 20, 30),
            child: Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: 'Enter a word/name',
                      labelText: 'Enter',
                    ),
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    onChanged: (name) {
                      value = name;
                      //value1 = name;
                    },
                  ),
                  RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      int sum=0;
                      if(value.trim().isNotEmpty)
                      for(int i=0;i<value.length;i++)
                        (value[i].toUpperCase() == value[i]) ? sum+= (value.codeUnitAt(i) - 64) :
                        sum+= (value.codeUnitAt(i) - 96);
                      print(sum);
                      Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => screen2(value: sum),
                      ));
                    },
                    child: Text('Submit'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          drawer: Drawer(
            child: ListView(
              children: <Widget>[
                UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.red),
                  accountName: Text('Yogesh Prakash'),
                  accountEmail: Text('test@dev.com'),
                  currentAccountPicture: CircleAvatar(
                    child: Image(
                      image: AssetImage(
                          'Image/105769079_10217500208479055_1053899048265455769_n.jpg'),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                ListTile(
                    title: Text('About'),
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AboutPage()),
                      );
                    })
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes this works. Thank you so much! :) Is there any way I can get in touch with you. Through LinkedIn or any other professional platform?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Map. Because it is basically a key-value pair.

ex:

```
var VariableName = {
  key : value, 
  key : value,
  key : value,
  key : value,
};
```

So if you want to make an A = 1, B = 2, ...

```
var myMapName= {
  'A' : 1, 
  'B' : 2,
  'C' : 3,
  'D' : 4,
};
```

So if you want to print 1 through A, you can call it as:

```
print(myMapName['A']);
```

so the output will be:

```
1
```

Comment: Just tried that but it gives me an error "Type string is not a subtype of type 'Map<String,int>'

Answer (score 0):

You can get the sum of ASCII value of your input string

```
sum=0;
String s;
for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    sum=sum+s.codeUnitAt(i)
  }
print(sum)
```